# Apache pig script, Error 1070: Java UDF could not resolve import

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig, user-defined-functions

I am trying to write a Java UDF with the end goal of extending/overriding the load method of PigStorage to support entries that take multiple lines.

My pig script is as follows:

```
REGISTER udf.jar;
register 'userdef.py' using jython as parser;
A = LOAD 'test_data' USING PigStorage() AS row:chararray;
C = FOREACH A GENERATE myTOKENIZE.test();
DUMP D;
```

udf.jar looks like:

```
udf/myTOKENIZE.class
```

myTOKENIZE.java imports org.apache.pig.* ande extends EvalFunc. the test method just returns a Hello world String.

The problem that I am having is that when I try to call the method test() of class myTOKENIZE I get Error 1070:  ERROR 1070: Could not resolve myTOKENIZE.test using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.] Thoughts?

Comment: As you found out already, you need to call the UDF using the full package name, udf.myTOKENIZE.test() in this case. An alternative is to use a define statement first like `define myTOKENIZE udf.myTOKENIZE();` Then you can simply use the UDF via myTOKENIZE.test()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After waaaaay too much time (and coffee) and a bunch a trial and error, I figured out my issue.

**Important note: For some jar myudfs.jar, the classes contained within must have package defined as myudfs.**

The corrected code is as follows:

```
REGISTER myudfs.jar;
register 'userdef.py' using jython as parser;
A = LOAD 'test_data' USING PigStorage() AS row:chararray;
C = FOREACH A GENERATE myudfs.myTOKENIZE('');
DUMP C;
```

myTOKENIZE.java:

```
package myudfs;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc;
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;
import org.apache.pig.impl.util.WrappedIOException;
public class myTOKENIZE extends EvalFunc (String)
{
    public String exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
        if (input == null || input.size() == 0)
            return null;
        try{
            String str = (String)input.get(0);
            return str.toUpperCase();
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw WrappedIOException.wrap("Caught exception processing input row ", e);
        }
    }
}
```

the structure of myudfs.jar:

```
myudfs/myTOKENIZE.class
```

Hopefully this proves useful to someone else with similar issues!

Comment: I've never named the package the same thing as my jar and I've used UDFs without problem. I think you found the incorrect root cause. What package was your classes originally in?

Answer (score 1):

As your UDF extends `EvalFunc` there should me a method called `exec()` in the class `myTOKENIZE`.

Your pig code would then look as follows:

```
C = FOREACH A GENERATE udf.myTOKENIZE(*);
```

Please read http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/udf.html#How+to+Write+a+Simple+Eval+Function

Hope that helps.

Comment: Fred, thank you for your response! I have followed that tutorial but I still get the same error when I try your method. `<file javaTest.pig, line 6, column 23> Failed to generate logical plan. Nested exception: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 1070: Could not resolve myTOKENIZE using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]`

When I attempt to follow the tutorial and call myudfs.myTOKENIZE(*) I get `ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. myudfs/myTOKENIZE (wrong name: myudf/myTOKENIZE)`

Comment: Actually, your suggestion to check the tutorial again did provide some insight. The reason calling myudfs.myTOKENIZE(*); did not work was because I had defined the package in myTOKENIZE.java as **package myudf** rather than **package myudfs**. I suspect that this was the root of all errors.

Answer (score 0):

So is myTOKENIZE in the package udf? In that case you'd need

```
C = FOREACH A GENERATE udf.myTOKENIZE.test();
```

Comment: I still get the same error when I try that. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is very late but I think the solution is that while  using the udf in your pig you have to give fully qualified path of the class with your package name.
`package com.evalfunc.udf`; and Power is my class name as
`public class Power extends EvalFunc<Integer> {....}`

Then while using it in pig first register the jar file in pig and then use the udf with full package name like:

`record = LOAD '/user/fsbappdev/maitytest/pig/pigudf/power_data' USING PigStorage(',');`

`pow_result = foreach record generate com.evalfunc.udf.Power(base,exponent);`